# Identification of Buddhist saints or sages

Tags: bodhisattva

I have a pair of antique statuettes which were made in Japan. I assume they are Buddhist saints or sages and I am hoping someone can identify who they represent:

[image: buddhist statuettes]

Comment: Perhaps they are but I'm not sure you can assume it: they remind me of Chinese statuettes I saw that were labelled "Daoist".

Comment: Buddhist monks are shaven. Since they have beards maybe they are non-Buddhist.

Answer (score 0):

He's Fuxing, one of the [Sanxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanxing_(deities)). Not Buddhist, he's a deity in Daoism and Chinese folk religion. This particular statuette looks a bit like Shouxing, but Shouxing is depicted as bald with an oversized head; Fuxing is usually depicted carrying a scroll or book.